# how to create grunt file to minified my js files

Tags: gruntjs

I have no idea how to minified my JSfiles using grunt.I hope someone can help me how to create grunt file in order to minified my js files step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run `npm init` to create a package.json.

```
npm init
```

Then, create a `Gruntfile.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'path/to/your/minified.js': ['src/script1.js', 'src/script2.js', 'src/script3.js']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

To minify your JS files I recommend [grunt-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

[Here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) is the documentation, but I will share the installation step by step.

Install the plugin via npm:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

Then, add this in your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
```

The basic configuration is like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'path/to/your/minified.js': ['src/script1.js', 'src/script2.js', 'src/script3.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Your `minified.js` file is the result of the minification of all your js files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have Gruntfile.js,how to generate the Gruntfile.js ?

Comment: if I run the command `grunt uglify` my Grunt.js file will be open to notepad++ :(